# Best approach to customize django admin page for existing app

Tags: python, django

I'm currently learning some basics of django by trying to implement admin page for the following app:
[PowerGSLB](https://github.com/AlekseyChudov/powergslb)

Though it already has nice UI based on W2UI my goal is to learn django and make role based authentication with help of django admin module. But it's actually not the point of the question.

I got stuck with presenting basic list of DNS records to user. DB model looks like this:

[db_model_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVvlv.png)

So, I ran through **inspectdb** and created models, based on this structure. After all, my *Records* model looks like this:

```py
class Records(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_type = models.ForeignKey(NamesTypes, models.DO_NOTHING)
    content_monitor = models.ForeignKey(ContentsMonitors, models.DO_NOTHING)
    view = models.ForeignKey('Views', models.DO_NOTHING)
    disabled = models.BigIntegerField()
    fallback = models.BigIntegerField()
    weight = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name_type} {self.content_monitor} {self.disabled} {self.fallback} {self.weight}"

    def get_all(self, in_var):
        self.result = dict()

        # Objects to get results from
        self.name_type_obj = NamesTypes.objects.get(id=self.name_type_id)
        self.content_monitor_obj = ContentsMonitors.objects.get(id=self.content_monitor_id)
        self.view_obj = Views.objects.get(id=self.view_id)
        self.names_obj = Names.objects.get(id=self.name_type_obj.name_id)
        self.domain_obj = Domains.objects.get(id=self.names_obj.domain_id)
        self.contents_obj = Contents.objects.get(id=self.content_monitor_obj.content_id)
        self.monitor_obj = Monitors.objects.get(id=self.content_monitor_obj.monitor_id)
        self.types_obj = Types.objects.get(value=self.name_type_obj.type_value_id)

        # Result vars
        self.result['domain'] = self.domain_obj.domain
        self.result['name'] = self.names_obj.name
        self.result['type'] = self.types_obj.type
        self.result['content'] = self.contents_obj.content
        self.result['ttl'] = self.name_type_obj.ttl
        self.result['id'] = self.id
        self.result['disabled'] = self.disabled
        self.result['fallback'] = self.fallback
        self.result['persistence'] = self.name_type_obj.persistence
        self.result['weight'] = self.weight
        self.result['monitor'] = self.monitor_obj.monitor
        self.result['view'] = self.view_obj.rule

        return self.result[in_var]
```

And my admin.py for my app looks like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Records


@admin.register(Records)
class RecordsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'get_domain',
        'get_name',
        'get_type',
        'get_content',
        'get_ttl',
        'get_disabled',
        'get_fallback',
        'get_persistence',
        'get_weight',
        'get_monitor',
        'get_view',
    )

    def get_domain(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('domain')

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('name')

    def get_type(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('type')

    def get_content(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('content')

    def get_ttl(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('ttl')

    def get_disabled(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('disabled')

    def get_fallback(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('fallback')

    def get_persistence(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('persistence')

    def get_weight(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('weight')

    def get_monitor(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('monitor')

    def get_view(self, obj):
        return obj.get_all('view')

    get_domain.short_description = "Domain"
    get_name.short_description = "Name"
    get_type.short_description = "Type"
    get_content.short_description = "Content"
    get_ttl.short_description = "TTL"
    get_disabled.short_description = "Disabled"
    get_fallback.short_description = "Fallback"
    get_persistence.short_description = "Persistence"
    get_weight.short_description = "Weight"
    get_monitor.short_description = "Monitor"
    get_view.short_description = "View"
```

It's actually working (here is an image [gslb_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SFyS.png)) but it's very slow, compare to original UI. Obviously this is because I have a lot of queries to database, instead of one big query, and here is the question - what is the best approach to do this in django admin?

I am using django v.3.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can modify the get_all(self, in_var) method

and could do like this

```
def get_all(self, in_var):
    self.result = dict()
    if in_var == "domain":
        return Domains.objects.get(id=self.names_obj.domain_id)
```

you can map in_var to model classes if you want
and same you can do with other variables